# How to use Tampermonkey to change the value of this element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, tampermonkey

In the following code, I want to change the value of "placeholder."

```
<input type="text" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="both" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Search box. Find messages, documents, photos or people" class="select-input react-typeahead-input k_w W_6D6F P_Z1E2YFn i_6LEV M_0 b_0 A_6EWk y_ZwubDW I_T p_R Z_N ui-autocomplete-input" value="" placeholder="Find messages, documents, photos or people" tabindex="10" maxlength="2000" spellcheck="false" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="on" autocorrect="off" data-rapid_p="2">
```

I wrote the following in Tampermonkey but it is not working.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Yahoo! Mail
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Make Yahoo! Mail nicer!
// @author       Jupiter
// @match        https://mail.yahoo.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    document.querySelectorAll('[placeholder="Find messages, documents, photos or people"]')[0].setAttribute("placeholder", "Search...");
})();
```

I tried the following as well but no luck.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    var a = document.getElementsByClassName("select-input.react-typeahead-input.k_w.W_6D6F.P_Z1E2YFn.i_6LEV.M_0.b_0.A_6EWk.y_ZwubDW.I_T.p_R.Z_N.ui-autocomplete-input");
    a.placeholder = "Search...";
})();
```

Comment: have you tried using that line in the js console to determine if it actually gets the element?

Comment: @user3229756 no, I don't really know how to do that.

Comment: Your code works, try it on the console here on [so]: `document.querySelectorAll('[placeholder="Search…"]')[0].setAttribute("placeholder", "Hello world");` . . . See [Browser Console - Firefox Developer Tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console)